# KDB: How to query with a set of columns

Tags: kdb

How do I do this corresponding SQL query:

```
select * from a where (col1, col2) in (select x, y from b)
```

So if I have

```
p:([]name:`John`Mary`David`James; age:52 49 18 23; hair:("black";"black";"blonde";"black"); eyes:`brown`brown`blue`brown; aa:("hello";"world";"hi";"there"))
```

How do I make this query work:

```
select from p where (hair, eyes) in (
select hair, eyes from p where any aa like/:("hello";"hi")
)
```

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `select hair, eyes from p where any aa like/:("hello";"hi")` is a table, so we need make a table from the `hair` and `eyes` columns for the where statement you want:

```
q)select from p where ([]hair;eyes) in select hair, eyes from p where any aa like/:("hello";"hi")
name  age hair     eyes  aa
--------------------------------
John  52  "black"  brown "hello"
Mary  49  "black"  brown "world"
David 18  "blonde" blue  "hi"
James 23  "black"  brown "there"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this using [fby](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#fby)

```
q)select from p where (any;any aa like/:("hello";"hi")) fby ([]hair;eyes)
name  age hair     eyes  aa
--------------------------------
John  52  "black"  brown "hello"
Mary  49  "black"  brown "world"
David 18  "blonde" blue  "hi"
James 23  "black"  brown "there"
```

`fby` allows you to apply aggregations based on a particular grouping, and then filter based on these aggregations. In this case some of the other solutions offered may be more readable, but `fby` is a powerful tool that can help avoid the need to used nested `select` statements in a lot of instances

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use equi-join (ej):

```
 q) ej[`hair`eyes;select from p where any aa like/:("hello";"hi");p]
```

```
name  age hair     eyes  aa
--------------------------------
John  52  "black"  brown "hello"
Mary  49  "black"  brown "world"
James 23  "black"  brown "there"
David 18  "blonde" blue  "hi"
```

Note that this will order result by columns used for equality. In this example it is by hair,eyes columns. So that order could be different from actual order of rows in table.

Read about ej here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#ej-equi-join